# Error while downloading the source code from google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, download

I am using the following command :

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <application-id> -V <application-version> <output-dir>
```

It then asks me for `googleusername` and `password`.

But after that it says

```
Unable to create directory /templates/<file name>: permission denied
```

It says this for all the files which need to be downloaded.

I have been given ownership of the application as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check the permission for the user by which you are running the `appcfg.py`.

When you download the app it will create `templates` directory to store all templates for that app. This error shows that user has no permission to create file on those directory.